# Simplifying jQuery addClass and removeClass to show what's selected

Tags: jquery

I made a simple script that tells you what's selected using jQuery remove class and add class but it seems to be way too much coding.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wz7Dv/

and here is the code:

```
$(".panel_nav li.kset").click(function(){
        $('.panel_nav li.gset,.panel_nav li.kset,.panel_nav li.rset,.panel_nav li.dset').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    $(".panel_nav li.gset").click(function(){
        $('.panel_nav li.gset,.panel_nav li.kset,.panel_nav li.rset,.panel_nav li.dset').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $(".panel_nav li.rset").click(function(){
        $('.panel_nav li.gset,.panel_nav li.kset,.panel_nav li.rset,.panel_nav li.dset').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    $(".panel_nav li.dset").click(function(){
        $('.panel_nav li.gset,.panel_nav li.kset,.panel_nav li.rset,.panel_nav li.dset').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Is there a way to strip it down?

Thank you

Comment: This is a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have links between `ul` and its `li` elements:

```
<ul id="panel_nav" class="panel_nav">
    <li class="gset selected"><a href="#generalsettings">General Settings</a></li>
    <li class="kset"><a href="#keyboardshortcuts">Keyboard Shortcuts</a></li>
    <li class='rset'><a href="#regionalsettings">Regional Settings</a></li>
    <li class="dset"><a href="#resetdefaults">Reset to Defaults</a></li>
</ul>
```

Moving the anchor inside the li requires a change in your CSS:

```
.selected a {color:red}
```

The javascript is very repetitive and can be cut down to this:

```
$("#panel_nav li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings(".selected").removeClass('selected');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wz7Dv/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `removeClass` lines to -

```
$('*:not(this)').removeClass('selected');
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zzxp8/

**EDIT**

I think you could boil the whole thing down to this -

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzxp8/2/

Comment: it needs few tweaks. The state l$("li").click(function() is definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#panel_nav a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz7Dv/2/)

Comment: Better still: `$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')`

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're doing the same thing for each list item, this will do what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
$(".panel_nav li.kset,.panel_nav li.gset,.panel_nav li.rset,.panel_nav li.dset").click(function(){
        $('.panel_nav li.kset.selected,.panel_nav li.gset.selected,.panel_nav li.rset.selected,.panel_nav li.dset.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

**EDIT**

Actually, it'd probably be the cleanest to just add a different class to the items you want to be able to select. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/otisskavier/Wz7Dv/3/.